# Is this sentence considered a double negative?

Tags: meaning, grammar, dictionaries, context, double-negation

*"There is no way it doesn't work on your phone."* Is this considered a double negative?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which clause has two negatives instead of normal negative polarity items?

Comment: Your sentence has an understood 'that' hiding between two clauses. So, one negative in each, and no doubles.

Comment: Which definition of double negative are you using? Are you actually asking if it's ungrammatical? Do you want to know what it means?

Comment: 'He did not say "No" ' is not what most class as a 'double negative' though there are two negations. And there's no problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

What the sentence is actually saying "There is no way **that** it doesn't work on your phone."

There is an implied "that". The sentence does not have a double negative.

Comment: This has already been said by Mr Baskin in a comment. While it is on this site regarded as OK to incorporate others' comments into one's answer, it is customary to acknowledge that this is what one is doing.